# joomla component to module

Tags: templates, joomla, module, components

I want to convert component to module apart from using plugin is ther any process to handle it.

(or)

whether we should code somethimg to make my mvc component to module .

(or)

is there any possibility to make my component to be placed at desired module position in my template

Regards,
noble

Comment: Your question does not make much sense. Please read @Lodder see answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can't convert a component to a module. A component, module and plugin are all 3 different things. Obviously if your component was something like a simple upload form, then this could be turned into a module but I doubt very much it is.

Nor can you place the component in a module position.

Judging by what you're asking, I am assuming that this is your own custom component, in which case, you should have had a little think and done a little research before you made it and brainstormed your exact requirements.

Answer (score 1):

1st thing You can't convert a component to a module. You have to understand the difference between them

***Components*** are the largest and most complex extensions of them all; they can be seen as mini-applications. Most components have two parts: a site part and an administrator part. Every time a Joomla page loads, one component is called to render the main page body. For example, Content (com_content) is the component which handles the display of content; users can view at the frontend of your site and, as an administrator, you can edit the content. Components are the major portion of your page because a component is driven by a menu item and every menu item runs a component.

Examples: Content (com_content), Banners (com_banners), Contact (com_contact), News Feeds (com_newsfeeds) and Web Links (com_weblinks)

***Modules*** are more lightweight and flexible extensions used for page rendering. These modules are mostly known as the “boxes” that are arranged around a component, for example: the login module. The footer is a module. Modules are assigned per menu item. So, you can decide to show or hide the logon module depending on which menu item the user is viewing. Sometimes modules are linked to components such as the “latest news” module which links to the com_content and displays links to the newest content items. However, modules do not need to be linked to components, as a matter of fact they don't even need to be linked to anything and can be just static HTML or text.

Examples: Banners (mod_banners), Menus (mod_menu), Who's Online (mod_whosonline)

[Read more](http://docs.joomla.org/Extension_types_%28general_definitions%29)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Joomla 1.5 then please refer this plugin it does exactly what you want. http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/2723/details